# How to insert string in table having space in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-conversion

I have to run below query but it is giving me error.

```
INSERT ALL
INTO tests VALUES
  (
    '25-10-2015 15:58:02',
    'a',
    238530
  )
INTO tests VALUES
  (
    '25-10-2015 15:58:02',
    'b',
    1234
  )
INTO tests VALUES
  (
    '25-10-2015 15:58:02',
    'c',
    4759
  )
INTO tests VALUES
  (
    '25-10-2015 15:58:02',
    'd',
    36734
  )
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

is there any way where I can insert string having space in string.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly insert a space as long as it's between the quotes (').  However, a date is a different type, and may need to be converted.  For example:

```
insert into tests values (TO_DATE('25-10-2015 15:58:02'...), 'd', 36734)
```

Note however, you need to reference the TO_DATE [syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) for proper formatting.  The main point is that you need to check the tests schema to verify it is looking for a date.  If it's a varchar format or some other string type, then it should work, unless your string is too long.  If it is a date however, you need to pass it a date.

Comment: Do not depend on the **NLS_DATE_FORMAT**. `TO_DATE`  is NLS dependent, you should mention the format model.

Answer (score 0):

```
'25-10-2015 15:58:02'
```

Above is a **STRING** and not a **DATE**. You must convert it explicitly into date using **TO_DATE** and proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

For example,

```
INSERT ALL
INTO tests VALUES
  (
    TO_DATE('25-10-2015 15:58:02','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
    'a',
    238530
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides Oracle's proprietary `TO_CHAR` you can also write a Standard SQL Timestamp literal (which is supported by most DBMSes including Oracle), `TIMESTAMP` followed by a 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss' string (independent of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT):

```
TIMESTAMP '2015-10-25 15:58:02'
```